# Handle Routes with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i'm working with backbone currently, and i'm stuck with a doubt, or may be,  a question with none sense.

Basically, i wanna do an list of articles based on category.

So, i was starting define my routes and no problem.

so, i have something like this:

```
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'home',
                'products': 'showProducts',
            }

});
```

What i want, is basically, when a user, click on some category, i wanna only update de products list below, not all my view. Ofcourse, i can do something inside view, detecting what category was selected, and then update only my content with those products.

But i think, that i prefer, that my app react according with my current route.

So, what i want, is someting like this:

```
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            ': 'home',
                    'foo:bar',
            'products/:category': 'showProducts',
                 },
                 home:function(){
                     this.close();
                     //render my home view
                 },
                 bar:function(){
                     this.close();
                     //render my bar view
                 },
                 showProducts:function(id){
                     this.close();
                     //render my products view
                 },
});
```

this works good, but i wanna avoid, that my header with categories list inside my productsWrapperView, be again re-render...

So, if my current page, is already an products view, if i select an category,

```
 "<a href='/products/2'>,
```

i just want to update my products list, not the entire view.. anyone knows an good approach?

makes any sense my question?

Comment: You should strongly consider using Marionette for this. It has support for regions (and layouts). If you don't want to use marionette, then take a look at how it implements regions and layouts and that may help. Also, have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477910/backbone-routing-with-subviews?rq=1 ?

Comment: well, i already read about Marionette, but must be some other approach using only backbone, to handle this situation..

Answer (score 0):

You should adopt subviews. The comments are right that marionette is good at this, but it is not required.

The thing to remember with Backbone is that it doesn't do a lot for you, but it is also not very opinionated. This leaves us a lot of scope to what we please within Backbone.

With subviews, I use the following function to assign subviews to DOM elements within a view:

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/9436132)

```
Backbone.View.prototype.assign = function(set, preventEmpty) {
        /*
        accepts an object of selectors:arrays of views

        maps each of the views to the selector
        */
        var self = this;
        //store all subviews
        self.assignments = _.extend(self.assignments||{},set);

        //
        _.each(set, function(views, selector) {
                if(!views) return;
                if(!preventEmpty) {
                    var el = self.$(selector).empty();
                } else {
                    var el = self.$(selector);
                }

                if(views instanceof Array != true) {
                    views = [views];
                }
                _.each(views, function(view) {
                    view.setElement(el).render();  
                });
            }, this);

    };
```

I can use to apply a subview from within a view:

```
init: function(){
    var SubView = new SubView({model: this.model});
    this.assign({
          '.sub-view':SubView
     });
}
```

Assigning the SubView.el to `.sub-view`.

Then, you can set subview to watch changes to the model, and update itself:

```
var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
  init: function(){
    var render = this.render.bind(this);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', render);
  }
}
```

This will only re-render the subview, not the parent view or any other view.

It is worth noting that this may not prevent the browser from repainting, but that may not be an issue for your application.

Comment: i'm already using subviews, not only one.. basically, i just want avoid browser from repainting.. that is my only problem.. sure, it is not an issue, but it's bad from user point of view.